# Как отправить файл в телеграм бот?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Подскажите пожалуйста в интернете не нашёл как отправить любой файл формата `.txt`, `.rar` есть только пример с фотографиями и сообщениями.

За любой пример буду благодарен.

Comment: Вроде для каждого типа ответа в библиотеках для телеграм-ботов есть отдельный объект. Если для отправки сообщения обычного это что-то типа `SendMessage`, то для файлов `SendDocument`.

Comment: @iksuy, У меня только `SendDocumentAsync` и вообще просто не знаю как отправить мне файл .txt в телеграмм бот просто примеров нету, или плохо ищу.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038304/how-can-use-senddocumentasync-in-telegram-bot-in-c

Comment: @iksuy, А откуда взять `new FileToSend` у меня после установки телеграм бота нету этой функции

Comment: А `IInputFile` есть?

Comment: @iksuy, Он у меня есть! А он что альтернатива какая-нибудь `FileToSend` ?

Comment: Чтобы файл отправлять нужно же сначала получить всю информацию о файле? И после отсылать его?

Comment: https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/blob/master/test/Telegram.Bot.Tests.Integ/Sending%20Messages/DocumentMessageTests.cs
Вот здесь прям в библиотеке есть тесты, где тестируется отправка файла

Comment: @iksuy, Вот спасибо, очень помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй Bot.SendDocumentAsync();

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]